# How do I allow AWS lambda resources in a private subnet VPC to communicate with the internet without using a NAT?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vpc

In my case i have an AWS aurora serverless database. The database is located in a private subnet to isolate the instance from public. If your lambda function needs access to the database you also have to attach the lambda to the private subnet and create security groups to grant access within your private subnet over the protocol and port used by the database.

But what is if your lambda needs external connectivity. For example to communicate to third party apps like paypal.

How do I allow AWS lambda resources in a private subnet VPC to communicate with the internet **without** using a **NAT**?

**Because of my fully serverless stack i like to avoid permanent fixed costs by using a NAT.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this.  As per the AWS docs, if your Lambda is running inside of a VPC and it needs internet access, you will need a NAT or an Instance.

You can read about this here:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Comment: Beat me to it by 2 seconds. I agree

Comment: another solution would be to use another public Lambda to handle tasks that need access to internet and call that from your private Lambda through PrivateLink. this way you don't need a NAT

Comment: Hi @RezaNasiri,

can you explain this in more detail? 

Lambda A is within a private subnet within a VPC. lambda A cannot communicate outside without NAT, ok so far. 

Lambda B is without VPC. Lambda B can thus communicate to the outside.  

For Lambda A to call Lambda B is a private link needed? Which services do I have to configure for this?

Comment: Lambda B will be public but triggered by a private API GW accessed through VPC endpoint configured to use api gw service. you will still pay for the vpc endpoint though. you can read more [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/)

Comment: There are lots of ways to do things, that doesn’t mean its best practice. This alternative solution (which should have been written as one) seems to add considerable complexity to an architecture, not to mention that it is simply replacing one cost with multiple others, some of which are also fixed and which may or may not ultimately cost less than the NAT gateway depending on usage, as well as added development overhead.